# Как при нажатии на ту же кнопку вернуть все состояния обратно? (без JQuery)

Tags: javascript, click, display

При клике, меняю значения display элементов, меняю цвет и значения *input*.

```
var deleteMarkerButton = document.getElementById('deleteMarkerButton');
var chooseMarkerDelete = document.getElementsByClassName('choose-marker__delete');
var chooseMarkerCheckbox = document.getElementsByClassName('choose-marker__checkbox');
var changeBasketColor = document.getElementsByClassName('cls-2');

deleteMarkerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < chooseMarkerDelete.length; i++) chooseMarkerDelete[i].style.display = 'block';
  for (var a = 0; a < chooseMarkerCheckbox.length; a++) chooseMarkerCheckbox[a].style.display = 'none';
  for (var b = 0; b < changeBasketColor.length; b++) changeBasketColor[b].style.fill = '#3c8bca';
  document.getElementById("addDeleteBtn").value = "Удалить";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить маркер
var check = true (false)
и после начала функции проверять состояние маркера и выполнять циклы в зависимости от значения маркера меняя значения маркера на противоположный каждый раз после нажатия.